# Is there any way to call JavaScript API call as we can have PHP curl call?

Tags: javascript, php, curl, call

I need data from different website with using of RESTapi call.
I have one PHP file which is using curl and giving me data with RESTapi call.
But here I wanted solution is that, I don't want to use any PHP file or Curl call, just wanted to RESTapi call with using JavaScript or Ajax Or jQuery. Is there any way to call like this?

Comment: what type of authentication is the REST API needing ?

Comment: Here is the link you can see @Satya
http://api.crossmrkt.net/restAPI.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script language="javascript">
function test()
{    
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var path="http://api.crossMRKT.net/rest/v1/{user_name}/list";
    request.onreadystatechange=state_change;

    request.open("GET", path, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Referer", "http://www.google.com");
    request.setRequestHeader("X-APikey","12345aaaaa67890aaaaa");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");

    request.send(null);
}
        function state_change()
    {
    if (request.readyState==4)
      {// 4 = "loaded"
      if (request.status==200)
        {// 200 = OK
                  console.log(response);
        }
      else
        {
        alert("Problem ...");
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

call this function on any button click or any event you want to attach and you should be through. Also make sure you supply your username in this line
`var path="http://api.crossMRKT.net/rest/v1/{user_name}/list";`

Comment: I checked with needed changes on above function, but still i am getting an error like "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed".

And there is a message like "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://api.crossMRKT.net/rest/v1/{user_name}/list. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

Comment: No, its giving me still same error.
Is is not allowing to us by adding this 
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");

Comment: then you need to get it done at php level your end or server end

Comment: Hummmmm, okey...
Thank you so much for this help :)

Comment: I am accepting it, but I don't have enough reputation to up you answer as I am new in stackoverflow.
But thank you so much again.